# My excel VBA recordset suddenly not working, any idea why?

Tags: vba, sharepoint, recordset

Below is my code which I wanted to pull data from a sharepoint list, but today it suddenly throws me an error, it has been working for years.

```
With cnt
 .ConnectionString = _
  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0,RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite;LIST={" & Sheet3.Cells(2, 11) & "};"
  .Open
 End With
 
 query = "SELECT [ID],[Name] FROM [User Information List] WHERE [email] like '%@xx.com%';"
 
rs.Open query, cnt
```

`Sheet3.Cells(2, 11)` <-- this stores my GUID

An error happened on the line `rs.Open query, cnt` saying

[image]

I'd tried to use macro record to work around with data extraction, but another part of my macro is also to write back to sharepoint list, but without recordset, it wouldn't work. Please help me.